# Zabbix snmpv3 - items doesn't work but snmpwalk does

Tags: snmp, zabbix, net-snmp

Im using zabbix 4.0.10 on centos 7 machine and i have an issue with cisco switch,
If i run snmpwalk it works fine from CLI , but as i use a template item it gives errors.
Sometimes i get user\password incorrect
And sometimes i get Timeout to the host ( which is not real as snmpwalk and snmpget continue to work from zabbix server CLI)

What am i missing ? i need to set somthing in the snmpd.conf ?
snmpd.conf:

```
com2sec notConfigUser  default       zabbix
group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser
group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none
rwcommunity  zabbix
rwuser zabbix authPriv
dontLogTCPWrappersConnects yes
syslocation Unknown (edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf)
syscontact Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmp.local.conf)
```

snmpwalk:

```
snmpwalk  -v3 -l authPriv -u zabbix-a SHA -A pass -x AES -X pass 10.0.0.1
```

(my password contained special chars)

And i have the macros i need in zabbix.

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix 4.x still doesn't support macros with SNMPv3. [Zabbix v5.0](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2613) would probably be compatible. 
You should enter all settings to EACH item of the host manually - through mass update setting. I've got through it already (tried almost everything).